# Pros and cons of using the zscore of a dataset before normalizing it during feature engineering?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

Normalization is a common feature engineering technique. However, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55498772/11170845) used standardize(zscore) on the dataset before normalizing it.

I think that would result in losing some of the information in data.

What are the pros and cons of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Normalizing an already normalized dataset should not change anything unless for some reason a different normalization scheme is used.

Answer (score 1):

Z-scores normalisation are a way to compare results from a test to a “normal” population and bring them to a same comparable scale. Advantages of ZScore can thus be:

$$ z\_score = \frac{x-\bar x}{\sigma} $$

The Z score normalisation has the following **advantages**:

1. Z Score can be used to compare raw scores that are taken from different tests
2. Z score takes into account both the mean value and the variability in a set of raw scores.

And the **Disadvantages** of Z score are:

1. Z Score always assume a normal distribution.
2. If the data is skewed, the distribution of the left and right of the origin line is not equal.